# Repeateldly Horizontal Stacking of Multiple Images Through a loop Using Python and CV2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I Want to Vertically stack the images through a loop, I am having an image out of the loop to that image I want to add the images vertically through a loop in python

[Required Output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea84k.png),

[Output what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytkhN.png)

```
image=cv2.imread(os.path.join(root,os.path.join(root,Value[0][0:3][1])))
for a in Value[0][3::]:
    image1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, os.path.join(root, a[1]))) 
    numpy_vertical = np.vstack((image, image1))
    cv2.imshow('Numpy Vertical', numpy_vertical)
```

it would be very helpful if someone helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
numpy_vertical=cv2.imread(os.path.join(root,os.path.join(root,Value[0][0:3][1])))
for a in Value[0][3::]:
    image1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, os.path.join(root, a[1]))) 
    numpy_vertical = np.vstack((numpy_vertical, image1))
    cv2.imshow('Numpy Vertical', numpy_vertical)
```

otherwise you're overwriting just stacked images again and again with the new image.